# htaccess - subfolder redirect not working

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdirectory

I have a problem with a .htaccess redirect and hope somebody could help me (I tried for 1,5 hours...).

What I want to do:
1) Redirect mydomain.com/en/ to mydomain.com (hide folder)
2) Still use subfolder mydomain.com/fr/ or mydomain.com/es as normal

My htaccess file (located in the main folder and not (!) in /en/):

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^en/  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ en/$1 [L]
```

What it does:
1) Works: Redirection from mydomain.com/en/ to mydomain.com works
2) Problem: When I enter mydomain.com/fr/ it redirects to mydomain.com/en/fr/

Question:
How can I get this redirection to only work on the /en/ folder and not on the other folders?
So that mydomain.com/fr/ would just stay mydomain.com/fr/?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an additional check:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^en/  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ en/$1 [L]
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/en%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/en%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^en/  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ en/$1 [L]
```

---

To remove the folder:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+en/([^\ \?]*)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, both options don't work. They do not hide the folder, so it stays at mydomain.com/en/ (as if nothing was in the htaccess).

Comment: @Student this only rewrites for URLs that don't have `/en/` in front. "Pattern" is `^(.*)$` (anything), and the rule's **target** is "/en/(anything)". There's no rule to redirect a URL like `/en/something` to `/something`, that's entirely different and is external

Comment: I don't get it to work as it should. I want to redirect the user depending on their country IP to a language version. So a user from France would get redirected to mydomain.com/fr/ when he enters mydomain.com (this is done via Javascript API from Maxmind and does work). The only thing I don't (!) want to happen is an English speaking user go to mydomain.com/en. Instead the URL should just be mydomain.com. When I add the two lines of code you gave me to remove the folder, I get a never ending loop, because it uses the file in the main directory instead of the one in subfolder /en.

Comment: @Student google "geoip", all of this is way out of the scope of your question

Comment: @Student plus, those rules [work perfectly fine for me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xjDRR.png), no loops

Comment: You are right. I thought there might be a simple solution to the problem, but it seems like a complex task. Thanks for your help, Jon Lin!

Comment: Yes, the rules itself do work. The loop is created because the javascript code in my index file in the main folder is used again and again (instead of using the index.html in subfolder /en).